# What is the best way to run Windows exe file on web

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu

I am working on the existing project.

Here is a exe file, when user open it, it get the config from the same directory will auto downloading the latest files(assets) from server to the current directory.

I don't know how the exe run, maybe it just run git pull or something like that. however we use this exe file to get the files and upload it using FTP.

Now, I need to create a new page on website, when user click the button, it will trigger/open the exe file on server side and download the latest.

I think i can use the Linux + Something like Wine or VM to run this file. Then When user click the button, will call the php file to run the bash script.

But When I run `wine Update.exe`
the error returned

```
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0014:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0014:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 183
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 14007
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x800736b7
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 800736b7
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 800736b7
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0016:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0016:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0018:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0018:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: Bad EXE format.....
```

Any solution for this? This is a very very small function in the project so I think moving the web server to windows is not allowed...

Comment: If this is very small function I would recommend to rewrite its logic on php. I bet it won't take a lot of time. Instead you'll get a stable solution.

Comment: @heximal I guess the exe may include some authentication or using something in .NET Framework, I don't have the source code so I need to run the exe.

Comment: The best way to run arbitrary code from unknown origin on a web server is to not run it at all. Anyway, what problem are you trying to solve? Make sure you understand the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).